# combinations of 3 from 6 digits without touching the order

Tags: matlab, math, combinations

Assume a 6 digit number abcdef. We want to generate all the 3 digit number combinations without changing the sequence of digits. That means
abc, …, ade, … def are fine but not bac. That’s because b is not supposed to appear before a. Matlab code is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
nchoosek({'a','b','c','d','e'},3)

ans = 

    'a'    'b'    'c'
    'a'    'b'    'd'
    'a'    'b'    'e'
    'a'    'c'    'd'
    'a'    'c'    'e'
    'a'    'd'    'e'
    'b'    'c'    'd'
    'b'    'c'    'e'
    'b'    'd'    'e'
    'c'    'd'    'e'
```